# Redis - sharding and GetHashCode

Tags: servicestack

We're playing with ServiceStack.Redis client running against a 2 node redis deployment.

We noticed that the method: ServiceStack.Redis.Support.ConsistentHash.AddTarget
uses the following code to map a node onto a circle:

string identifier = node.GetHashCode().ToString() + "-" + i;

In this case a node is of type ShardedConnectionPool with GetHashCode overridden as:

return name.GetHashCode();

This has problems I think:

First of all GetHashCode result is not guaranteed to be the same across deployments. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx

"The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across versions of the .NET Framework and across platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of the .NET Framework"

The implications for sharding are rather severe as clients running on sligtly different instances will map the keys differently.

Secondly, GetHashCode() is being relied on by other classes (e.g. Dictionary) and this implementation may cause some issues. There're many requirements around GetHashCode, such as
"Derived classes that override GetHashCode must also override Equals to guarantee that two objects considered equal have the same hash code; otherwise, the Hashtable type might not work correctly."

I imagine the intention was to have no additional constraints on the "node" type in , however given above it'd probably be cleaner to require the class to implement an interface with method providing fields that should form the key.

As a quick fix (we actually ran across this problem) we just overridden ToString() method to return the name and adjusted the AddTarget method.

Thoughts?

Comment: This question is off topic. This doesn't really ask a specific programming question, rather it requests an opinionated discussion about an implementation, as such it is not a good fit for SO.